# How to install a gadget on wikidata?

Tags: wikidata

In my own local wikidata, how can I install a new gadget, say, [slurpInterwiki](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadget-slurpInterwiki.js)? It is the kind of gadget that I want (js file, enable on Preference of a user)

In the Preference of user currently, I can only see 2 gadgets which are `checkConstraints` and `authorityControl`

Answer (score 0):

Wikibase (software of Wikidata) is an extension of MediaWiki, thus installing a gadget on Wikibase/Wikidata works the same way as on any other MediaWiki installation.

Generally, you need to perform two steps:

1. Copy the JavaScript code of the gadget to your wiki. The page title must have the form "MediaWiki:Gadget-gadget_name"
2. Add a new line to [[MediaWiki:Gadgets-definition]] with the content `mygadget[ResourceLoader|dependencies=]|mygadget.js|mygadget.css`

The dependencies of slurpInterwiki are defined in https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Gadgets-definition. Easiest way is just to copy the relevant line on this page to the corresponding page on your wiki.

More detailed instructions to install gadgets can be found on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Gadgets.